# Brownian Motion, Markov property, Durrett Ex 8.2.2

Tags: probability

Let $T_0 = \inf\{s>0: B_s = 0\}$ and let $L = \sup\{t \leq 1: B_t = 0\}$. $L$ is for left or last. Use the Markov Property at time $0 < t < 1$ to conclude

$P_0(L \leq t) = \int p_t(0,y)P_y(T_0 > 1-t) dy$.

Let $\theta_t$ be the shift transformation. I want to know why $1_{\{T_0 > 1-t\}} \circ \theta_t = 1_{\{L \leq t\}}$.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to make the $\omega$ variable explicit. We have
$T_0(\omega)=\inf(s>0: B_{s}(\omega)=0)$ and so, by the definition
of the shift operator $\theta_t$, we get
$$T_0(\theta_t\omega)=\inf(s>0: B_{s}(\theta_t\omega)=0)
=\inf(s>0: B_{s+t}(\omega)=0).$$
Therefore 
$$t+T_0(\theta_t\omega)=\inf(s>t: B_s(\omega)=0).$$

This means that $t+T_0(\theta_t\omega)>1$ if and only if 
$B_s(\omega)\neq 0$ for all $s\in (t,1]$. This is true if and only 
if $L(\omega)\leq t$.

Comment: "This means that $t+T_0(\theta_t \omega)>1$ if and only if $B_s(\omega) \neq 0$ for all $s \in (t,1]$" I don't agree with that. If $B_s(\omega) \neq 0$ for all $s \in (t,1]$, this does, in general, not imply that $t+T_0(\theta_w)$ is strictly larger than $1$ (...because it might be equal to $1$).

Comment: @saz By continuity of sample paths, $B_s(\omega)=0$ at $s=t+T_0(\theta_t\omega),$ provided the latter is finite. So if $t+T_0(\theta_t\omega)=1$, then $B_1(\omega)=0.$

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Ah, right... thanks.